# Azure Storage Queue to Cosmos DB

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azureservicebus, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to receive a payload from a http trigger and send payload with an envelope to the Service Bus and eventually Cosmos DB so I can perform CRUD operations.

The payload is properly received and given an envelope and the envelope is properly sent to and received from the Service Bus. Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out how to send a message from the Service Bus to Cosmos DB without a brand new http trigger so I have resorted to trying to set up a Storage Queue in order to send the message. If it is possible to do this with a Service Bus, please let me know how. Otherwise, I have no clue why I am getting this error when running my program. Below are all of the code segments and error messages:

Handler.java:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

public class Handler {

    @FunctionName("HttpHandler")
    public HttpResponseMessage runHttp(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req, ExecutionContext context) {
        try {
        
            // request to String (payload)
            String request = req.getBody().get();
            // build Envelope
            MessageEnvelope env = cf.buildEnvelope(request, context);
            // log 
            CfLog envelope = cf.log(env, context, request);
            // send envelope to Service Bus Queue
            ServiceBusSend.send(envelope);
            // send envelope to Storage Queue
            context.getLogger().info(StorageQueueSend.send(envelope));
            // Create in Cosmos
            //context.getLogger().info(CosmosOperation.create(envelope, context));
            
            context.getLogger().info("Made it 1");
            return req.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Data logged").build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log the exception
            context.getLogger().severe(e.toString());
            return req.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred").build();
        }
    }

    @FunctionName("ReceiveFromQueue")
    public void runReceiveFromQueue(
            @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name= "envelope", queueName = "hyperscalerapi-queue", connection = "hyperScalerAPIServiceBus")
            CfLog envelope, final ExecutionContext context) {
        try {       
            context.getLogger().info(envelope.toString());
            context.getLogger().info("Made it 2");
            // Cosmos DB upload

        } catch (Exception e) {
            context.getLogger().severe("An error occurred while processing the message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}`
```

StorageQueueSend.java:

```
import com.azure.storage.queue.QueueClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.queue.models.QueueStorageException;

import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Environment;

import com.azure.storage.queue.QueueClient;

public class StorageQueueSend {
    public static String send(CfLog envelope) {
        try{
            System.out.println(System.getenv("hyperScalerAPIStorageQueue"));
            QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClientBuilder()
                                            .connectionString(System.getenv("hyperScalerAPIStorageQueue"))
                                            .queueName("hyperscalerapistorage-queue")
                                            .buildClient();
            queueClient.sendMessage(envelope.toString());
            return "Envelope added to storage queue\n";
        } catch(QueueStorageException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}`
```

CosmosOperation.java (function currently commented out because above function doesn't work):

```
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Document;

/**
 * Azure Functions in Java with Cosmos DB Trigger.
 */
public class CosmosOperation {
    @FunctionName("create")
    @CosmosDBOutput(name = "database", databaseName = "hyperscalerapi-cosmos-dev", collectionName = "Items",
            connectionStringSetting = "cosmosDBConnectionString")
        public static String create (
            @QueueTrigger(name = "envelope", queueName = "hyperscalerapi-queue",
            connection = "hyperScalerAPIStorageQueue") CfLog envelope,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
                return "Payload: " + envelope.getPayload() + "\nWith ID: " + 
                envelope.getExecution().getCorrelationId() + "added to Cosmos DB";
            }
}`
```

Error messages when running (never actually completes run, I have to terminate):

```
[2023-02-27T17:12:43.295Z] Function "ReceiveFromQueue" (Id: ece2405b-1ddf-4f48-a1d9-9d35f4fe4d83) invoked by Java Worker
[2023-02-27T17:12:43.386Z] Executed 'Functions.ReceiveFromQueue' (Succeeded, Id=ece2405b-1ddf-4f48-a1d9-9d35f4fe4d83, Duration=173ms)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.571Z] Feb 27, 2023 12:12:44 PM io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer exceptionCaught
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.576Z] WARNING: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x62de8a42]
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.578Z] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.<init>(int, int, int, boolean, boolean, int, boolean, boolean)'
...
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.751Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:192)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.752Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.753Z]      at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:304)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.754Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.757Z]      at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:172)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.760Z]      at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:445)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.762Z]      at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:400)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.765Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.766Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.768Z]      at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:554)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.770Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.771Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.776Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.778Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.780Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.781Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.782Z]      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.782Z]      at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:517)
[2023-02-27T17:12:44.783Z]      at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.setFailure(TransportConnector.java:471)
```

This is just a snippet of the error messages. It keeps going.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about the error message itself but looks like you are returning a log message instead of a JSON string of the document. Refer [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-java#queue-trigger-save-message-to-database-via-return-value) from the docs and the same of which can be done using a Service Bus Queue Trigger as well.

Here is the code sample from the docs for reference

```java
@FunctionName("getItem")
@CosmosDBOutput(name = "database",
  databaseName = "ToDoList",
  collectionName = "Items",
  connectionStringSetting = "AzureCosmosDBConnection")
public String cosmosDbQueryById(
    @QueueTrigger(name = "msg",
      queueName = "myqueue-items",
      connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")
    String message,
    final ExecutionContext context)  {
     return "{ id: \"" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\", Description: " + message + " }";
   }
```

If you need to store the envelope object as is, you should just return it directly as a JSON string.